# Javascript in my index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select dropdown list on my website
http://www.wearemovingto.com and on line 118 I have the code for the dropdown list. At the rate I am going the index page is going to look really messy as I need to put in around another 200 countries, and we all know google hates that.
I have tried linking the dropdown list to a js file but that didnt work, yes my js is below par. All I want to do is have all the dropdown code in a js file but still have the dropdown list on the website

basically look like this on the source
From line 118

```
<div class="vmapSelect"></div>
<div id="vmap" style="width: 960px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your JS code?

Comment: Google doesn't like long menus? Every site that asks for a country from a menu does this, I really doubt it affects google ranking.

Comment: I don't have Js code. I need to put the Dropdown list into a js file.

Comment: Basically I want to cut all the Dropdown code and put it into a js file. When I was SEOing my website I was told that the Dropdown code will affect my ranking.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of country codes and names. Then loop through it, adding them as options to your country menu.

```
var countries = [ 
    { code: "US", name: "United States"},
    { code: "CA", name: "Canada"},
    ...
];
$.each(countries, function(code, name) {
    $("#country").append($("<option>", {
        text: name,
        value: code
    }));
});
```